# ¿Cómo puedo parsear un polinomio en C++?

Tags: c++

Estoy trabajando en un código en codeblocks con lenguaje C++.

Tengo un arreglo de objetos tipo string, donde cada casilla almacena un polinomio diferente de la forma:

```
P1=2#3#-7#2#9#1;
P2=5#2#10#1#-7#0;
P3=4#2#-1#1#-10#0
```

Donde el primer numero es la base, y el segundo es el exponente,separados por el `#`, y siempre vienen de a pares como en los ejemplos. También se posee la función `int stoint(string var)`, que retorna el string ingresado transformado a entero.

¿Cómo podría separar cada polinomio, y guardar las bases y los exponentes arreglos tipo int para 1 polinomio y así hacerlo con los demás, respectivamente?

Esta es la funcion donde debo trabajar:

```
void agregar(nodo a[],string b[],int larpo)
```

Donde en `b[]` se almacenan los polinomios en `larpo`, el largo del arreglo con el número de polinomios y `a[]` un arreglo de estructuras del siguiente tipo:

```
struct nodo
{
    int base[20];
    int exp[20];
};
```

Donde en cada estructura deben guardarse las bases y los exponentes de 1 polinomio y así con todos.

Answer (score 2):

Solo como por dejar en claro, **Codeblocks** es solo el IDE donde escribes tu código, bien habrías podido usar **zinjai**, Dev-C++, Netbeans e incluso Bloc de notas.

En cuanto tu pregunta, puedes usar [strtock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para partir la cadena luego juegas un poco con el resultado, puesto que ya conoces la estructura, mas o menos así:

```cpp
void agregar(nodo a[],string b[],int larpo) {
    for (int i=0; i<larpo; i++) {
        char *  seccion = strtok ((char *)b[i].c_str(),"#");
        int j=0;
        // Sabiendo que la estructura maneja un patron así: base#exp#base#exp#base#exp
        while (seccion != NULL)
        {   
            string cadena = seccion;       // Solo porque usted definio que stoint requiese un «string»
            a[i].base[j] = stoint(cadena); // base
            seccion = strtok (NULL, "#");  // #
            a[i].exp[j] = stoint(cadena);  // exp
            j++;                           // Proximo indice para el nodo
        }
    }
}
```

A continuación te muestro el funcionamiento en cuanto a fraccionar la cadena, usando el ejemplo que dejaste en la descripción:

http://codepad.org/F6Qlyy55

Espero te sea de utilidad.